# Removing duplicates from a sorted int[] using binarysearch

Tags: java, arrays, binary-search, duplicates

I have a rather large int[] which is sorted using `Arrays.sort()` .. I need to remove the duplicate elements from the array.

This question originates from sedgewick's Algorithms book 1.1.28

> 1.1.28 Remove duplicates. Modify the test client in BinarySearch to remove any du- plicate keys in the whitelist after the sort.

I tried to create a noDupes() method which takes in an int[] and returns an int[] with duplicates removed

The rank() methods are from sedgewick's code.which does the binary search

```
public static int[] noDupes(int[] a){
    Arrays.sort(a);
    int maxval= a[a.length-1];
    int[] nodupes = new int[maxval];
    int i=0;
    for(int j=0;j<a.length;j++){
        int rnk = rank(a[j],nodupes);
        System.out.println(a[j]+" rank="+rnk);
        if (rnk < 0){
            System.out.println(a[j]+" is not dupe");
            nodupes[i] = a[j];
            i++;
        }
    }

    return nodupes;
}
public static int rank(int key,int[] a){
    return rank(key,a,0,a.length-1);
}

public static int rank(int key,int[] a,int lo,int hi){
    if(lo > hi) return -1;
    int mid = lo+(hi-lo)/2;

    if(key < a[mid])return rank(key,a,0,mid-1);
    else if(key > a[mid])return rank(key,a,mid+1,hi);
    else return mid;
}
```

When I ran this with a sample array

```
int[] a =new int[]{2,2,2,3,4,4,5,6};
int[] ret = noDupes(a);
```

I am getting some unexpected output..even after 2 is added to the nodupes array, the rank for an existing element is -1..

```
2 rank=-1
2 is not dupe
2 rank=-1
2 is not dupe
2 rank=-1
2 is not dupe
3 rank=-1
3 is not dupe
4 rank=-1
4 is not dupe
4 rank=4
5 rank=-1
5 is not dupe
6 rank=-1
6 is not dupe
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6
    at ...noDupes(BinSearch.java:85)
    at ...main(BinSearch.java:96)
```

I couldn't figure out what I am doing wrong..can someone help?

Comment: why can't you use `Set<Integer>`?

Comment: @sanbhat - because that's not what the exercise is about.

Comment: I am trying to learn how to do this without using any library classes..I think the exercise means to solve this using binarysearch

Comment: Something wrong here. If the array is already sorted you can find the duplicates by a linear scan. No binary search required.

Comment: @EJP you are right..linear scan will do

Comment: Okay..I finally found out why the above code gives erratic result.. the rank(a[j],nodupes) call in the for loop is wrong ,because nodupes initially contains all zeros..`[0,0,0...]` ..when you put elements into it ,the array becomes [2,0,0..0] and then you are calling rank() on it so as to do binary search.To do binary search ,you need to have the array sorted.But since nodupes array is unsorted,you get wrong result..

Comment: Did you misunderstand the question? I think it's asking you to remove duplicated items in a sorted array, before the array is going to be used in BinarySearch. I did not look carefully on your code. But it seems that you mixed BinarySearch into this question which is out of topic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it this way

```
public static int[] noDupes(int[] a) {
    Arrays.sort(a);
    int noDupCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (i == 0 || a[i] != a[i - 1]) {
            noDupCount++;
        }
    }
    int[] a2 = new int[noDupCount];
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (i == 0 || a[i] != a[i - 1]) {
            a2[j++] = a[i];
        }
    }
    return a2;
}
```

Comment: wouldn't that take O(n) time ?

Comment: it will, but I dont think you can make it go without iterating over full array

Comment: You can speed this up by using a larger-than-necessary array, looping once and doing System.arraycopy

Answer (score 3):

just add all the array values to the HashSet it will automatically remove duplicates and gives you unique values and then again convert it to array that you required

Comment: This won't keep the order - although of course you should do the sort after removing duplicates.

Comment: Well, use a SortedSet instead of an HashSet and the order will be kept.

Answer (score 2):

If you have your array sorted and if you want to remove duplicates I think you don't need to use binary search for that.

when you sort an array, duplicate elements will be adjacent to each other.

E.g. Array = {9,8,9,1,2,5,2,5,1}
After sorting Array = {1,1,2,2,5,5,8,9,9}

You can use following way to remove duplicates (inplace)

```
int a[] = {sorted array}

for(int i=0,target=0;i<a.length-1;i++) {
  if(a[i]!=a[i+1]) {
     a[target++] = a[i];
  }
}
a[target++] = a[a.length-1];
for(int i=target;i<a.length;i++) {
a[i] = 0; // fill in the values which you don't want.
}
```

will remove duplicates in one pass only

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

```
int[] nodupes = new int[a.length];
```

nodupes array is going out of bound.

Note: I am not sure if logic that you are using is the best for the problem. But this should solve your exception.

Answer (score 0):

This code will help you.

```
public Integer[] removeDuplicates(Integer[] input){
        Integer[] arrayWithoutDuplicates = null;
        Set<Integer> set = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();
        for(int i : input){
            set.add(i);
        }
        arrayWithoutDuplicates = (Integer[]) set.toArray();
        return arrayWithoutDuplicates;
}
```